# How to restrict input to letters only in Delphi XE5?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

Ran into a couple of problems using a code that only lets the user input alphabetical characters and a backspace.

When I compile my program using RAD studio 2010, apart from Vcl problems in the Uses clause, It compiles correctly, all working fine. However when I try and compile using XE5, I get an error: `E2010 Incompatible types: 'Word' and 'AnsiChar'`
If anyone can point me in the right direction it would be great!

Code below:

```
procedure TFRMStuTakeTest.DBEDTWord01KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
(*only return value if alphabetic *)
  if Key in ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', #8] then
  else
    Key := #0;
end;
```

Sorry if there's something about procedures having to be from clean projects (i.e. unnamed/ not descriptive)

Comment: What happens if your users speak a language other than English?

Comment: @David
Delphi was originally a language for English speaking/reading users, but Unicode enables foreign characters, so I presume that I could use Unicode if I were to adapt it to a different language?

Comment: The Delphi that you use fully supports Unicode. Your code does not. It's easy to support non English speakers. Would you like to know how to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OnKeyDown` is designed to deal with virtual key codes (those that are referred to using the `VK_` constants), not individual letter and number keystrokes.

Use `OnKeyPress` to process individual characters, not `OnKeyDown`.

```
procedure TFRMStuTakeTest.DBEDTWord01KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
begin
  if not CharInSet(Key, ['A'..'Z','a'..'z', #8]) then
    Key := #0;
end;
```

Better still, use the `EditMask` on the underlying `TField`, and set a valid mask for alpha characters using something like `'LLLLL;0;_'`, which would require 5 letters between '['A'..'Z','a'..'z']', and will handle all of the validations, editing keystrokes, and so forth.

```
YourTable.FieldByName('Word1').EditMask := 'LLLLL;0;_';
```

See the documentation for [TField.EditMask](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Data.DB.TField.EditMask) for more information, and follow the link at the bottom to [TEditMask](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.MaskUtils.TEditMask) for details about the mask characters. (There's an editor for the `EditMask` property in the Object Inspector; they're the same as those used by `TMaskEdit`, so you can drop one of those on your form and click the `...` button on the right side of the `EditMask` property to access it.)